# Solving polynomial equations given some constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations

I want to solve a polynomial equation but I know that it can have **exactly one** root. Is there some method to solve these kinds of problems.

for example-
$$A(1+x)^4 + B(1+x)^3 +C(1+x)^2 + D(1+x) +E=0$$

Here $A$ is always negative, and $B,C,D,E$ are always positive.

Comment: "**Exactly one** root" where?  This one will always have at least two real roots, one $< -1$ and one $> -1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let  $ f(x)=A(1+x)^4 + B(1+x)^3 +C(1+x)^2 + D(1+x) +E=0$

Since $A$ is negative, $f(-\infty) = f(\infty)=-\infty$ and if this polynomial has just one root that should be a double root. Therefore you can take $gcd(f(x),f'(x))$.

Comment: I did not understand, since x is unknown how can I take gcd of f(x) and f'(x) ?

Comment: by application of  extended Euclidean algorithm on f(x) and f'(x)

Answer (score 0):

A [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation) such as this can be solved using radicals, but it's rather complicated.  If you have numerical values for $A,B,C,D,E$ you're probably better off using numerical methods.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What do you mean by numerical methods?

Comment: @Noober He means approximation techniques using calculus, such as Newton's method or a variety of others.

Answer (score 0):

Having *exactly* one root means *exactly* one thing: the following equation has the form $A(x - r)^4$.  So you need to write this in expanded form:

$$
A(x - r)^4 = Ax^4 - 4Ax^3r + 6Ax^2r^2 - 4Axr^3 + Ar^4
$$

then we have:

\begin{align}
\alpha(1+x)^4 + \beta(1 + x)^3 + \gamma(1 + x)2 + \delta(1 + x) + \epsilon =&\ \alpha x^4 + 4\alpha x^3 + 6\alpha x^2 + 4\alpha x + \alpha \\
&\ + \beta x^3 + 3\beta x^2 + 3\beta x + \beta \\
&\ + \gamma x^2 + 2\gamma x + \gamma \\
&\ + \delta x  + \delta \\
&\ + \epsilon \\
=&\ \alpha x^4 + (4\alpha + \beta)x^3 + (6\alpha + 3\beta + \gamma)x^2 + (4\alpha + 3\beta + 2\gamma + \delta)x + (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta + \epsilon)
\end{align}

This creates five equation with 6 uknowns (although I have a feeling $A$ can be set to equal a multiple of *any* of the $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \epsilon$).